# What does Hinduism think of sex with animals?

Tags: scripture, animals, sex

Does Hinduism support sex with animals or is against sex with animals?

Comment: My vote alone closed your question (normally it requires 5 close votes) .. do you have any objection about the closure?

Comment: @Rickross no objections sir, thank you for informing me of such a question, that answer you wrote to that question answered my question.

Comment: Thanks Rajam  ....

Comment: @Rickross no problem